# Is there any opencv function to add edges to white background?

Tags: python, opencv, matplotlib

I'm creating code for number plate recognition with CCTV. When i'm trying to get the edges of number plate, the edges are not rectangle. How can i add edges in the white background?

```
import numpy as np
import cv2,imutils
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
image = cv2.imread('car2.jpg')
image = imutils.resize(image, width=500)
gray = cv2.cvtColor(image, cv2.COLOR_BGR2GRAY)
gray = cv2.bilateralFilter(gray, 11, 17, 17)
ret,thresh = cv2.threshold(gray,128,255,1,cv2.THRESH_BINARY)
edged = cv2.Canny(thresh, 170, 150)
```

I want to add edges in the white background, How can i achieve to add edges through the white background?

Below is a visual explanation of the problem:

Actual output:

[image: Actual output]

Expected output:

[image: expected output]

Contours:

[image: contours]

Comment: So you want to detect rectangles rather than detect edges?

Comment: yes, you are right, i have added contours image too? Please check it.

Comment: (1) with a CCTV, the plate will not always be a rectangle (depends on the point of view, may be a parallelogram). (2) by changing the threshold of canny filter, you should be able to have "more edges"